# Nodejs setInterval callback issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, setinterval

I am facing a issue in extracting the current time value from setInterval function.

Here is my nodejs code

```
export const countDownTimer = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
var time = 120;
var resultantTime = '';
let countdown = setInterval(timer, 1000);

    function timer() { 
      let min = Math.floor(time / 60); 
      let sec = time % 60; 
      sec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;
     let finalTime = `${min}:${sec}`
     deriveTime(finalTime)
  
      time--;
      if (min == 0 && sec == 0) clearInterval(countdown);
      }

      
     function deriveTime(finalTime){
        resultantTime = finalTime
      }

       console.log("resultantTime:", resultantTime);
        res.status(200).send(resultantTime);

 } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
```

When I check resultantTime in my browser console it becomes undefined. However If I check the same console log inside the deriveTime function , then it gives proper result.

I want to send this resultantTime to front-end so I want to bring this resultantTime value out from setInterval function. Please help.

Comment: The `setInterval ` is async, when you send the `resultantTime`, the timer function hasn't run. so you can't get the value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to make deriveTime function async and also add await  before  await  deriveTime(finalTime)

Comment: I used npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-interval-async   to implement async functions properly .  In spite of that also I could not able to get resultant time                                                                                                              
                                               
      Why timer function does not nun again?

Comment: That indenting is giving me emotional damage